# Why doesn't diborane act as an oxidising agent

Tags: organic-chemistry

I read that diborane has 3 center's sharing 2 electrons.

Shouldn't it be easier for diborane to accept one more electron and act as an oxidising agent than a reducing agent .

Could someone tell me what's wrong my reasoning?

Comment: A sodium cation has a positive charge. Shouldn't it want to accept some electrons and act as an oxidizing agent? If you don't think that makes sense, then consider if the situation with diborane is analogous.

Comment: In this case, the electron acceptor is a  Lewis acid, not an oxidizer.